# Seeing the diff of a conflicted file in git with --word-diff

Tags: git, diff

Let's say I have attempted a merge from branch A to branch B -- the merge failed because there are conflicts in file F.

Until now I have been doing a

```
git diff --word-diff HEAD:F master:F
```

which gets boring after a while. Is there some alternative out of the box command that allows me to avoid this, or will I have to save this little script and make it accessible somewhere in my computer's $PATH?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try a `git alias` ?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever the scope of a repeated operation is going to be limited (i.e. a relatively short session inside a single terminal) and not likely to occur again in the near future, I prefer to wrap it in a bash function in the current shell. This avoids the problem of having to find a good name for the script before putting it in $PATH.

In your case, typing the following line into the shell

```
function mydiff() { git diff --word-diff HEAD:"$1" master:"$1"; }
```

will enable you performing diff with a much shorter command `mydiff F`.

Answer (score 1):

As [Leon answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38463643/1256452) you can make a tiny shell function (or shell alias) for this, or as [Frodon commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462660/seeing-the-diff-of-a-conflicted-file-in-git-with-word-diff#comment64329326_38462660) you can make a Git alias.

More usefully, during a conflicted merge, the local (`--ours`) and other (`--theirs`) commit IDs are conveniently named `HEAD` and `MERGE_HEAD` respectively.  Hence you don't have to hard-code the name `master` into your shell function, shell alias, or Git alias, and:

```
[alias]
    wdiff = "!f() { git diff --word-diff HEAD:\"$1\" MERGE_HEAD:\"$1\"; }; f"
```

would do the trick here, for instance.